# Can't print whole content in C

Tags: c

Got a huge problem. Let's say, that I have pointer to a large string (~1500 characters) and I want to print it. What I get in the result is only a part of that string. After the program prints that part it asks me for a newline. After I press enter the program prints the rest of the string and terminates. It happens when I try to run my program in terminal or with IDE. If I try to debug it, it works perfectly. I need it to print whole string without terminating the program. So, here's the code (there's lots of mistakes in the code):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<string.h>

#define SOCKET int        // Apibreziame sinonima 'int' tipui, kad butu
                          // unix ir WIN sistemoms bendras kodas dirbant
                          // su soketu deskriptoriais.
#define closesocket close // Apibreziame sinonima close () funkcijai
                          // closesocket (), kuris yra analogas Windows
                          // tipo sistemose. Tai del kodo suvienodinimo.
#define INVALID_SOCKET -1 // Apibreziame del kodo suvienodinimo, klaidos
#define SOCKET_ERROR -1   // situacijai nusakyti konstantas, kurios WINSOCK'o

#define MAX_CH 255
#define POP3_PORT 110
#define MAXLEN 1024

int main()
{
    SOCKET socketE;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    struct hostent* h = NULL;

    char* Packet = NULL;

    Packet = (char*)malloc(MAX_CH);
    memset(Packet, 0, sizeof(Packet));

    printf("POP3 server: ");
    gets(Packet);

    /*******{ 
    client connects to the mail server and other stuff
    server sends greeting message
    client receives greeting message 
    }*******/

    if (!strstr(Packet,"+OK")) {
        print_error(Packet);
    }
    else {
        printf("%s", Packet);
        int printedData = 0;
        while (1) {
            Packet = (char*)realloc(NULL, 1);
            memset(Packet, 0, sizeof(Packet));
            gets(Packet);
            strcat(Packet, "\n");
            if (SOCKET_ERROR == SendPacket(&socketE, Packet)) {
                print_error("Error on sending data to mail server.\n");
            }
            memset(Packet, '\0', sizeof(Packet));
            if (SOCKET_ERROR == ReceivePacket(&socketE, &Packet)) {
                print_error("Error on receiving data from mail server.\n");
            }
            if (!strstr(Packet,"+OK")) {
                fwrite(Packet, 1, strlen(Packet), stdout);
                break;
            }
            printf("%s", Packet);  //THIS IS WHERE THE PRINT PART COMES
        }
    }
    close(socketE);
    return 0;
}
```

Okey, so I have found out that this if clause (I mean, even if this if is false) stops program from printing all the content. If I remove/comment it, I got my program working correctly. Is it possible, that this one causes all the problems?

```
if (!strstr(Packet,"+OK")) {
    fwrite(Packet, 1, strlen(Packet), stdout);
    break;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), especially the part about how to ask questions. I also recommend you to read http://sscce.org/ and http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/ as those texts will help you create better questions to post here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
Packet = (char*)realloc(NULL, 1);
memset(Packet, 0, sizeof(Packet));
```

causes undefined behavior. It allocates a single byte (why would you ever do this?) and then clears `sizeof(Packet)` bytes, which on most typical systems today is either 4 or 8 bytes. Thus, it writes outside the allocated memory. Note that `sizeof` cannot track dynamic allocations, so this whole pattern is wrong.

Also, please note that dynamic memory allocation can *fail*; you must check the return value of every call to `realloc()` before relying on the returned pointer being valid. If it's `NULL`, you can't access through it.

Further, just like with `malloc()`, [please don't cast the return value of `realloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169) in C.

Comment: Not to mention that `ReceivePacket()` isn't told how big the buffer it's reading data into is (it probably assumes that the buffer is `MAXLEN` in size).

Comment: Let's say that I have fixed these mistakes. Still I can't get all the data printed. Any other solutions?

Comment: @trimprim: Have you looked at what's in the buffer using a debugger?  Are there null characters in there?  It's hard to guess at what might be wrong when we'd be guessing at the code's state.

Comment: Yep, I guess so, because after receiving part of packet and placing it into a pointer of characters, I memset whole buffer with '\0'

Answer (score 0):

Try to add flush after `printf`:

```
printf("%s", Packet);
fflush(stdout);
```

`printf` use `stdout`, which is line buffered. So `printf` texts can be partly flushed (printed) if there is no `'\n'` in the end of the string.

In your case unflushed text is flushed when you type the newline.

Comment: I have tried it already. It seems, that bigger part of string got printed then it was before, yet it asks me for newline symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Stdout is line buffered and characters in the stdout stream are saved until a newline is output or input is read from any stream attached to a terminal device, or if the stream buffer gets full. 
so you may either put the '\n' character in your printf like printf("%s\n",Packet); or just disable the stdout buffering using setbuf(stdout, NULL); for printf to print the complete string